# HTML Email a form

Tags: html, email

In my HTML I have  form that contains three fields. I want to email the contents of these fields to a@b.com when the "submit" button is pressed, but right now when I click "submit" it brings the user to log in to gmail. Is there a way to make a one-click email button?

Comment: What HTML form? What have you tried? What are you using?

Comment: Post up your code please

Comment: You need a server-side implementation to do a one-click email; client side emailing is going to require the user to be logged in, and to click *send*.

Comment: @dbaseman but i think user can also send mail by `action="MAILTO:a@b.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"`

Comment: @RegisteredUser yes, but that's always going to take the user to their default mail client (Gmail, Outlook, etc), so "one click" emailing doesn't work in that sense.

Comment: @dbaseman ya ,exactly but i think with only html nothing else more

Answer (score 2):

this is what i understand from your question ,yes its possible to email on one click by email

```
<form action="MAILTO:a@b.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="your name" /><br />
  E-mail:<br />
  <input type="text" name="mail" value="your email" /><br />
  Comment:<br />
  <input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50" />
  <br /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

to create the one-click email button without let user go to gmail you need to do server side implementation and if you even want to do it without reloading the page than you can do this by the Ajax (i would recommended you to use the Ajax with jquery) and to mail you can use the [php mail  function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) but i would recommend you to use the [php mailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

example

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "this is demo message ";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, 
// we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send
mail('example@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

but it will show some un wanted information with mail like `example@example.com via example.com`

to hide the via example.com you need to setup the **SPF (Sender Policy Framework )** record in the in your website or **DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail)** . [link to know How to add DomainKeys/DKIM and Sender ID records to my DNS?](http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=100)

link to [generate the DKIM](http://dkimcore.org/tools/)